# Name of the song in episode 293 of Bleach when Suì-Fēng attacked Aizen

Tags: music, bleach

In episode 293 of *Bleach*, there's a song playing when Suì-Fēng attacked Aizen with Shunpo (clones) and Nigeki Kessatsu (Death in Two Steps).

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably *Senna* by Shiro Sagisu from album *Memories of nobody*